# Change the background image in the media prompt

Tags: background, yaml, media, prompt

I want to switch the image background of a media prompt, because it's only
blank above and under media window.

[image]

I saw that on the example from google, they switch this background.

[image]

Can you help me with code in YAML?

```yaml
candidates:
  - first_simple: {}
    content:
      media:
        optional_media_controls:
          - PAUSED
          - STOPPED
        media_objects:
          - name: Précisions
            description: 'Abayan, le sage'
            url: 'https://sndup.net/4m3z/01_mixdown2.mp3'
            image:
              large:
                url: >-
                  https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ea/GANDALF.jpg
        media_type: AUDIO
```

Comment: What is your current code? What language/system is it in? `media` and `prompt` don't give enough context.

Comment: I upload the thread ;)

Thanks for your help !